# forEach not working properly on EJS template

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I was trying to grab all the students from the database collection and have them display row by row in the EJS template. I thought a forEach would be the best way to do this but it only displayed one entry when there were 6. Any advice on how I could display all entries would be greatly appreciated.

The table

```
   <table class="table col-md-4">
    <thead class="thead-inverse">
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Math Level</th>
        <th>English Level</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <% students.forEach(function(student){%>
    <tr>
    <td><%=student.firstname %></td>
    <td><%=student.lastname %></td>
    <td><%=student.english_level%></td>
    <td><%=student.math_level%></td>
    </tr>
    <%})%>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

In this GET request I fetched all the students from my database and the page on which they would be displayed

```
//INDEX - show all students
app.get("/students", function(req, res){
    // Get all students from DB
    Student.find({}, function(err, allStudents){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render("students",{students:allStudents});
            console.log(allStudents);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If you haven't already done so, do a console.log(students); somewhere in your ejs template and see what's coming out.

Comment: The console.log shows the students..so they are there but are not displaying properly I guess..?

Comment: I figured out the solution, I just needed to clear the database of all the previous entries and start from scratch.